# Where exactly(path in file system) to store the uploaded files in a Java Web App(JSP, Servlets) so that it is OS independent?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload, path

So I've been researching for over a month and I've read most of the answers regarding this question;
Even @BalusC's answers have not given me exactly what I want.

I am developing Java web apps using jsp, servlets & apache tomcat as the servlet container and eclipse as the IDE.
When I have to give an option of uploading files to user, where to store the files???
I've read answers that say not to use 'getServletContext().getRealPath("/")' over and over again bcoz it flushes all data when app is redeployed or server is cleaned.
Also I've read answers that say it is bad idea to store files in DB as blob because it is not as efficient as file system(file systems are meant for this usage)

Ok so in which folder do I save the uploaded files then?
So that should work both in windows and linux environments.

Some say to choose a location outside servlet container, but if I do that then once file is uploaded I won't be able to access it in the application directly right?

I also need to generate URL for these files(images and songs) later so that I can provide it in my REST API for the android app users. This can only be done if the file is in servlet container(tomcat working directory) right? Not outside.

Comment: Database. Definitely database.

Comment: If you're looking for a hardcoded "path" you can use for all environments, there is no such thing.  The usual solution to this problem is to have a deployment configuration `.properties` file that contains environment-specific information, _such as the path for storing uploaded files_.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes I understand there is no such thing as hardcoded path that works for all environments. What you are saying is really helping me, can you please give an example for both linux as well as windows where(path) I can configure my app to store uploaded files.

Comment: I can't give you a specific path as that depends on the specific system.  If you own the system (i.e. have root/Admin rights) YOU get to decide.  If not, the system admin will provide you with a directory.

Comment: @JimGarrison Ok. If you can help me out a little more, I'll be very specific with paths now. In my machine apache tomcat resides at C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\ So now is it fine if I have a new directory after this like C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\uploads and store my files here? Would this pose any issues later when I host this in my linux machine? I'll will obviously be using relative path instead of the absolute path that I have pasted here. But since it is inside server folder I just wanna know is it fine?

Comment: Try `C:\Uploads` - really, it's ***up to you***.